# Проблема с кодировкой при отправке файла из библиотеки 1С C++ Windows на сервер Go linux

Tags: 1с, golang, кодировка, c++

Добрый день.

Братья по разуму, выручайте :)

В общем проблема в следующем.

Имеется компонента для 1С написана на С++ работает из под винды. Эта компонента, вот таким нехитрым способом с помощью curl кидает на сервер файлы.

```
    for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); it++) {
    if (common::FileExists(it->second) == true) {
        curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, it->first.c_str(), CURLFORM_FILE, it->second.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
    } else {
        common::WriteLog("Файл " + it->second + " не найден");
    }
}
```

Сервер написан на Go, работает под Linux (Centos 5) Его задача принять и сохранить файл(ы) у себя на диске, НО **обязательно под реальным именем, менять нельзя**.
Делается это примерно так:

```
for i:=0; true; i++ {
    file, handler, err := formFile(reader, "extra_"+strconv.Itoa(i), 0)
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    data, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err2 != nil {
        break
    }
    web.FilePutContents(uploadPath+"/"+handler.Filename, string(data))
}
```

Функция formFile выглядит примерно так:

```
func formFile(reader *http.Request, key string, index int) (multipart.File, *multipart.FileHeader, error) {
if reader.MultipartForm == multipartByReader {
    return nil, nil, errors.New("http: multipart handled by MultipartReader")
}
if reader.MultipartForm == nil {
    err := reader.ParseMultipartForm(defaultMaxMemory)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
}
if reader.MultipartForm != nil && reader.MultipartForm.File != nil {
    if fhs := reader.MultipartForm.File[key]; len(fhs) > index {
        f, err := fhs[index].Open()
        return f, fhs[index], err
    }
}
return nil, nil, ErrMissingFile
}
```

Функция web.FilePutContents так:

```
func FilePutContents(filename string, data string) bool {
err := ioutil.WriteFile(filename, []byte(data), 0775)
setErr(err)
if err == nil {
    return true
}
return false
}
```

И вот собственно проблема, файлы с кириллическими именами сохраняются в поломаной кодировке, как это исправить?

Что пробовал:

1) Пробовал из компоненты передавать имя файла отдельно, как есть и в base64

2) Пытался на сервере имена файлов переводить в utf8 с помошью https://code.google.com/p/go-charset/

Собственно все, на этом идеи у меня закончились.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо конвертировать не ASCII строки. До выхода Go 1 прикрасно работал пакет exp/utf8string. К сожалению, в Go 1 его сключили. Я компилирую его вручуную и использую как и раньше. В официальной документации рекомендуют использовать новый пакет [utf8](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/).